# Using Ubuntu at the moment. Not a fan so tried to install Windows 8.1 no luck so far

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

So basically I bought a new tower for my computer from eBay and it already had Ubuntu installed on it. I'm not a huge fan so I went out and bought Windows 8.1. When I tried to install it, it said "Where would you like to install Windows?" I had 2 partitions to choose from and when I tried both of them, it said they needed to be in the format of NTFS. When I try to format my hard drive from ext4 to NTFS it comes up with this message:

```
Error unmounting filesystem

Error unmounting /dev/sda1: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
 (udisks-error-quark, 14
```

How do I stop this and successfully format my hard drive? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format a drive / partition that is in use, so you will need to boot your system from a live disc or usb and format the drive from there.

You can use an Ubuntu live disc and **Gparted** to format the drive as NTFS.

If you do not have one already, [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and use **Start up disc creator** which is already installed on your Ubuntu system to create a live / install disc.

Next boot your computer using the live install disc you created, select **Try Ubuntu** and when you reach the desktop search the dash to find and open **Gparted**, then you can format & partition the drive as you wish.